# Fantasy novel, one armed protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm sketchy about the one armed protagonist. Might have only been missing a hand. Also might have been a good/great swordsman before losing the arm. He may have been on a quest to restore his arm.

Hunt for the novel was triggered by seeing the name Tycho, who may have been a supporting character or military leader, and was possibly a construct. The term homunculus comes to mind.

I don't recall the protagonist having any supernatural powers, though there was magic present in the world.

Book might have been considered Young Adult, hard to tell now since I was reading all sorts of fiction back then. Time frame read was approximately 15-20 years ago. If it was part of a series, I only ever read this one book.

Will attempt to come up with more details over the weekend.

Comment: OK, Well up-vote from me, I may have a look later but with a character name (even if only possible) it seems quite likely it'll be found!

Comment: The first paragraph sound a lot like *Jamie Lannister*. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there any chance it was *[The Book of Shadows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0708995268)*, the first book of the *Nightshade Chronicles*?

[image: Book Cover - The Book of Shadows]

> Nightshade was once the best warrior in Delgarvo. But defeat at the hands of the evil sorcerer, Avoch-Dar, has left him without his sword arm -- a warrior deeply wounded. Now Avoch-Dar has returned and intends to lay waste to Delgarvo. Only Nightshade can stop him. But what use is a one-armed hero against such powerful enchantment? Then a prophecy is revealed. Only by recovering the fabled Book of Shadows can Nightshade defeat Avoch-Dar. To do otherwise is to court certain death.

I haven't read it but some of the details match and Tycho is mentioned in one of the reviews.

> It all starts when the kings champion, dalveen leandor, goes on a quest to recover the book of shadows in order to stop the evil sorceror avoch-dar. along the way he meets shani, a knife-thrower with spunk, craigo meath, a mercenary, tycho, a made being with strength and mind power and many more who aid him on his way through the perils of zenobia to recover the book. a definate must-read. Shani Rules!!

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Would you mind elaborating on which details match the description?

Comment: @F1Krazy will do when I have a minute :)

Comment: Well, you beat me to it.

Comment: :) Sorry, didn't mean to step on your toes. But we have a lot of drive-by people, so I often provide the basic summary from a review site.

Comment: That's the one! Not sure why I spent the better part of a day racking my brain trying to remember it, should have asked here first! Now wondering what subconscious impact it had on me choosing this account name for everything online since forever...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no worries - that's definitely what i was doing!