# Trilogy where the main character is missing a hand but manifests a shadow hand

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find name of a trilogy.  I read one of books in 2006-2007.

The main character has a missing hand but has shadow powers and a shadow hand appears. He is the chosen of a shadow god and his second (backup chosen) is a former thief with an eye patch who fights with dual swords.

There is a third companion who is half-human/half-demon, the son of a demon king, who is losing control of himself to the demon side.  There is also a noble paladin warrior with a sigil of a rose that believes in light/good.

The first three fight a dragon and the demon hybrid uses dark magic to make the dragon feel suicidal and stop moving so they can deliver a killing blow.  The dragon is brought back to life out of pity and is freed.

Also, an evil goddess is trying to take over the world.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170154/fantasy-novel-one-armed-protagonist

Comment: @Valorum Doesn't really seem to be a match: https://archive.org/details/bookofshadows0000nich/

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is probably the *Forgotten Realms* trilogy [*The Twilight War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11787) (2006-2008) by Paul S. Kemp.  The first book is [*Shadowbred*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?184282) (2006).

[image: Cover of "Shadowbred" showing two shadowy, snarling, shadow-cloaked figures fighting, the one left and above wielding a black sword while the one right and below claws at the first]

The one-handed shadow user is Everis Cale:

> The slate sea turned blue under the rising sun. The light crept across the water and stung Cale's flesh. The rays caused **Cale's shadowhand**, the hand with which he had driven a punch dagger into the gut of the God of Thieves, to dissipate into nothingness. **He had lost the original hand** to a slaad's jaws while doing Mask's will. His transformation into a shade had regenerated it, but only in darkness or shadow. It seemed to him fitting that it was the instrument through which he had wounded Mask.

Cale is First of Five of the god Mask:

> Cale answered the glare with one of his own and dared speak his thoughts aloud. "A bluff. You chose me and I chose you. You said so yourself. I may be your tool, but you are also mine. **I am your Chosen**, the First of Five. I may need you, but you need me, too."

The one-eyed character is Drasek Riven, Second of Five:

> A figure materialized out of the darkness of the archway. Cale recognized Riven from his stature and stance, from **the two sabers that hung from his weapon belt**. He wore a black cloak rather than his usual crimson.
>
> He did not bother to hail Riven and Riven did not bother to hail him. Cale started up the drawbridge; Riven started down. **Cale was Mask's First; Riven was Mask's Second**. They met in the middle, cloaked in the night.
>
> "He told me you were coming," Riven said. "I have been waiting."
>
> Like the tower, Riven looked much the same as the last time Cale had seen him — short, muscular, and precise. He wore his long black hair pulled back and tied. **The scarred hole of his right eye** looked like a pit in the swarthy skin of his face. The signature sneer and stained teeth nested in a black goatee. He wore a black disc on a chain around his throat — a symbol of Mask.

The third is Magadon, son of the devil Mephisto, and is half-devil:

> The devil laughs. "He calls himself a 'tiefling' but he knows that is not true. A tiefling is touched by a devil's blood. *Touched*. **He has a devil for a *sire*.** He is a half-fiend and then some. The lies are all that make it tolerable. Without me, without the lies, he would be lost."

The paladin with a rose holy symbol is Abelar Corrinthal:

> The younger Corrinthal stood a head taller than his father. He displayed a stronger jaw, thicker frame, shorter beard, and no gray hair, but his eyes and nose looked so much like Endren that he could not be missed as the nobleman's son. He wore a heavy blade at his belt—its pommel was a stylized rose—and **a holy symbol on a necklace around his throat—another rose, symbol of Lathander the Morninglord**.
>
> Elyril hated him instantly. This newcomer's **soul shone like the sun**. She refused to look at his shadow as he approached them.
>
> "My son," Endren said. "Abelar Corrinthal."